# How does a kids club on a cruise contact you if there is a problem?

Tags: cruising

My wife and I are getting ready to take our first with our 4 year old son on NCL. We plan on using the "kids club", but I don't understand is how they get in touch with you if there is a problem. On their website [FAQ 19](http://www.ncl.com/freestyle-cruise/freestyle-family-fun/youth-programs/faq#19) states:

> Will the Youth Staff contact me if my child is crying?
>
> Yes. Since Norwegian is not able to provide one-one-care or
>   babysitting, the parent(s) will be called to pick up their child after
>   15 minutes of continuous crying.

Does this mean we need to bring our cell phones? The website mentions a beeper system in [FAQ 18](http://www.ncl.com/freestyle-cruise/freestyle-family-fun/youth-programs/faq#18):

> Can the Youth Staff assist my child in the washroom?
>
> Parents should be aware that Youth Counselors are not able to assist
>   children in the washrooms. This includes pulling up/down pants,
>   buttoning/unbuttoning pants, and/or wiping assistance. A beeper or
>   handy phone will be issued to alert you when your child needs
>   assistance. Beepers and handy phones do not work ashore. At least one
>   parent will have to stay on board when their children are in our Youth
>   Program.

Is this used for all children or only toddlers that cannot go to the bathroom completely independently?

Comment: I can't answer your question definitively, but I highly doubt cell phones would work aboard the ship, especially once you have left the shore. As the second quote says, they will issue you with a beeper/handy phone (provided by them) to contact you on if any issues arise. Failing that, they will likely try your room phone or the ship-wide PA system to locate you.

Comment: @Sam Cell phones should work on the [MCP network](http://www.ncl.com/about/staying-connected-sea-cellular-phone-service-texting). Have you ever heard an announcement over the PA system for someone to report to the kids club. That would seem likely to put the parent, and possibly other parents, into a fit of hysteria.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub - I highly doubt such an announcement over the PA would perturb anyone except the parents involved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NCL specifically provides pagers only for children in diapers, consistent with your FAQ:

> [NCL [...] have more limited pager use, providing them to parents of
>   special-needs kids and/or those in diapers.](http://www.cruisecritic.com/articles.cfm?ID=155)
>
> [Norwegian Youth Counselors are not able to change diapers or pull-ups.
>   Parents are given a beeper or handy phone to alert them when their
>   child needs a diaper change.](http://www.usatoday.com/experience/cruise/best-of-cruising/best-lines-for-children-under-3/2412019/)
>
> [Unlike Carnival and Disney, NCL's youth staff is not permitted to
>   change diapers; hence, parents of diaper-wearing tots receive pagers
>   and are paged when they need to come change junior.](http://www.smartertravel.com/travel-advice/top-five-baby-friendly-cruise-lines.html?id=3740134)

Other parents would have to be hailed over the PA system.  It looks like NCL is betting that the only children, or at least the massive majority, that would spend 15 minutes crying continuously are also those that would be in diapers.